# Limiting the number of columns in a chart in an access-report

Tags: sql, ms-access, charts, report, ms-access-2010

In Microsoft Access I have a table called Cons:

```
Person | Date_Consumption | Consumption
```

For a number of people every first day of the month over a couple of years I am writing down the consumption.

I want to create a report for each person with a chart displaying the consumption over the last 12 months.

I can create the chart without the 12 month restriction with this query:

```
SELECT (Format([Date_Consumption],"mmm")) AS Date_Cons, Consumption FROM Cons;
```

How can I only display the last 12 months.
I tried to work with SELECT TOP 12 of the DESC sorted table, but this fails because I don’t know how to limit the selection to the person that is currently active on the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql Limiting of results is done by where clause.
you can get the last 12 months data by restricting the the last date after which you want the results.

```
SELECT (Format([Date_Consumption],"mmm")) AS Date_Cons, Consumption FROM Cons 
where Date_Consumption > '08-Feb-2012'(if you run your report today)
```